# Implementing an AJAX POST API call in wordpress

Tags: ajax, api

I'm attempting to make a POST request to an API. I've created a javascript file in my theme and i have tried two approaches so far:

**Approach 1:**

```
$.ajax({
        headers:{  
            "Content-Type":"application/json"               
        },   
        data:{
            "command": "request",
            "data": {
                "api_key": "my_api_key",
                "api_username": "my_api_username",
                "vendor_type": 2,
                "from": {
                  "from_name": "",
                  "from_lat": "",
                  "from_long": "",
                  "from_description": ""
                },
                "to": {
                  "to_name": customerLocation,
                  "to_lat": cityLat,
                  "to_long": cityLng,
                  "to_description": ""
                },
                "recepient": {
                    "recepient_name": name,
                    "recepient_phone": phone,
                    "recepient_email": email,
                    "recepient_notes": ""
                },
                "delivery_details": {
                  "pick_up_date": pickupdate,
                  "collect_payment": {
                    "status": false,
                    "pay_method": 0,
                    "amount": amountTotal
                  },
                                      "return": true,
             "note": " Sample note",
              "note_status": true,
              "request_type": "quote"
            }
            },
            "request_token_id": requestToken
            },
        type: 'POST',
        url:"https://apitest.sendyit.com/v1/",
        success: function(response){
           console.log('success');
           console.log(response);
        },
        error: function(response){
            console.log('error');
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
```

The above code will not return a response payload from the API as any call will be blocked because of CORS(Cross-Origin Resource Sharing)

**Approach 2**

I then attempt to pass the endpoint to my `functions.php` file as follows:

```
//make api call to sendy
function foo() 
{
     echo 'https://apitest.sendyit.com/v1/';
}
add_action('wp_ajax_foo', 'foo' );
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_foo', 'foo' );
```

I declare an `ajaxUrl` variable in my theme's header.php file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var ajaxUrl = "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>";
</script>
```

Then format my Ajax call as shown below:

```
$.ajax({
        headers:{  
            "Content-Type":"application/json"               
        },   
        data:{
            "action": 'foo',
            "command": "request",
            "data": {
                "api_key": "my_api_key",
                "api_username": "my_api_username",
                "vendor_type": 2,
                "from": {
                  "from_name": "",
                  "from_lat": "",
                  "from_long": "",
                  "from_description": ""
                },
                "to": {
                  "to_name": customerLocation,
                  "to_lat": cityLat,
                  "to_long": cityLng,
                  "to_description": ""
                },
                "recepient": {
                    "recepient_name": name,
                    "recepient_phone": phone,
                    "recepient_email": email,
                    "recepient_notes": ""
                },
                "delivery_details": {
                  "pick_up_date": pickupdate,
                  "collect_payment": {
                    "status": false,
                    "pay_method": 0,
                    "amount": amountTotal
                  },
                                      "return": true,
             "note": " Sample note",
              "note_status": true,
              "request_type": "quote"
            }
            },
            "request_token_id": requestToken
            },
        type: 'POST',
        url:ajaxurl,
        success: function(response){
           console.log('success');
           console.log(response);
        },
        error: function(response){
            console.log('error');
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
```

But this is giving me a `400 (Bad Request)` error.

I should mention that i have correctly set up my javascript file in the `functions.php` file:

```
wp_enqueue_script('sendy', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/sendy.js', array('jquery'));
wp_localize_script('sendy', 'wc_checkout_params', array('ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')));
```

Would like therefore to request for assistance in setting up my POST endpoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got the error `400 Bad Request` because the `Content-Type` header is `application/json`:

```
$.ajax({
  headers:{
    "Content-Type":"application/json"
  },
  data: {
    ...
  },
  ...
});
```

And when the request content is a JSON string, the `$_REQUEST['action']` which WordPress uses to identify the proper AJAX action (which is `foo` in your code) is not available (i.e. it's a `NULL`).

So based on your code, and with your second approach, you can just omit the `headers` part.

```
$.ajax({
  // No "headers" here.
  data: {
    ...
  },
  ...
});
```

### UPDATE

You can use [`wp_remote_post()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_remote_post/) to make the external API request from the `foo()` function; *example*:

```
function foo() {
    if ( empty( $_POST['data'] ) ) {
        wp_die( 'Missing data' );
    }

    $post_data = wp_unslash( $_POST['data'] );
    $post_data['command'] = wp_unslash( $_POST['command'] );
    $post_data['request_token_id'] = wp_unslash( $_POST['request_token_id'] );

    $api_url = 'https://apitest.sendyit.com/v1/';
    $response = wp_remote_post( $api_url, array(
        // Set the Content-Type header.
        'headers' => array(
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
        ),
        // Set the request payload/body.
        'body'    => json_encode( $post_data ),
    ) );

    $res_body = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response );
    echo $res_body;

    wp_die();
}
```

Comment: You're right Sally. Thanks. Now this opens up a different discussion.. The response now returned after removing the header is the endpoint string i.e. https://apitest.sendyit.com/v1/. The entire purpose of passing the endpoint in the functions.php file is to avoid passing it in the ajax(which will result in a CORS issue). And i should mention that the data being passed to the API are obtained using jquery. So how do I pass the data this way and use the endpoint to receive the required response payload?

Comment: Check the updated answer.

Comment: Excellent. I now make a successful API call and get the data i need. The last bit it grabbing the required value, in this case the shipping cost, and updating the checkout page using ajax. i've been looking around and the most common way i've seen is `$( document.body ).bind( 'update_checkout' );` but doesn't seem to work. i'm passing it in my `success` callback as: `success: function(response){
    $( document.body ).bind( 'update_checkout' );
    
    var responseData = JSON.parse(''+response+''); ...` but not getting the page reload. any idea how i can get this last bit to work? thanks

Comment: I can only say that you're not binding any callback to the `update_checkout` event - it should look like `$( document.body ).bind( 'update_checkout', function(){ ...your code... } )`. But I have no idea of the relation between the `update_checkout` and the things you want to do. And if you need further help, you can ask a question on Stack Overflow. (I'd be happy to help, but please do not ask new questions via the comments)

Comment: ah ok. will do just that as i'm currently stuck. thankyou so much for your input

Comment: hi Sally.. i've done just that here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/326902/woocommerce-checkout-page-ajax-refresh-shipping-cost would be grateful for any input you might have

Comment: WooCommerce [questions](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/woocommerce) are [off-topic](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here on WPSE. I did see that question on SO though, so if nobody posts a response, I'll check it later on.

Comment: ok. thankyou for your continued input